# discord runtimeError ('SSL is not supported.')

Tags: python, discord.py

When I open Pycharm, create and run a discorded bot, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sghan/PycharmProjects/discordbot/milkbot.py", line 36, in <module>
    client.run('NzE2OTk0ODcyNDAxMzMwMjA3.XtYgFA.JOVxgA__TwM9TKnFs905n6zftFM')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET','/users/@me'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 483, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 859, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 953, in 
    _create_direct_connection
    sslcontext = self._get_ssl_context(req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 901, in _get_ssl_context
    raise RuntimeError('SSL is not supported.')
RuntimeError: SSL is not supported.
```

The source code is like this:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Logged in as')
print(client.user.name)
print(client.user.id)
print('------')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!test'):
await client.send_message(message.channel,'test!!!!')

elif message.content.startswith('!say'):
await client.send_message(message.channel,'leave message')
msg = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=15.0, author=message.author)

if msg is None:
await client.send_message(message.channel,'Please enter within 15 seconds. Retry: !say')
return
else:
await client.send_message(message.channel, msg.content)


client.run('token')
```

Comment: What do you think the problem is? What have you tried to fix it so far and how can someone reproduce this problem on their end?

Comment: ho, it is not end

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **change** your **TOKEN**, you've just revealed it by posting your traceback.

Also, it seems you're using an old version of `discord.py` which is depreciated.

Try to update your `discord.py` module to a version >= 1.3 and try again.

You should dump your current `discord.py` version by running this command :

```
pip3 uninstall discord.py
```

[Click here to see how to install the new version.](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)